# What's wrong with this subscription? I get updates but the view is not refreshed

Tags: angular, graphql, subscription, apollo, graphql-subscriptions

I'm trying to refresh a counter with a subscription done with ApolloGraphql.
**It's almost working**since I can see in the dev-tool the following data coming from the server on event:

```js
{
  "type": "subscription_data",
  "id": 0,
  "payload": {
    "data": {
      "dealVoteAdded": {
        "voteCount": 16,
        "__typename": "VoteType"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Before this event, the counter was 15. It should go to 16 since that's the new value I get but nothing changes. **The view is never refreshed. Why?**

Here is my code:

**ParentComponent**

```
export class DealVoteComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public voteCount$;
  private voteCounterSub$;

  @Input() deal: Deal;

  constructor(private dealService: DealService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * Get update of dealVoteCount
     */
    this.voteCount$ = this.dealService.getDealVote({
      externalId: this.deal.externalId
    })
      .map(({data}) => {
        console.log("voteCount$ data", data);
        return data.getDealVote.voteCount;
      })

    /**
     * Subscription of dealVoteCount
     */
    this.voteCounterSub$ = this.dealService.dealVoteAdded({
      externalId: this.deal.externalId
    }).subscribe({
      next: (data:any) => {
        this.voteCount$.updateQuery(prev => {
          const newCount = {
            getDealVote: {
              voteCount: data.dealVoteAdded.voteCount
            }
          };
          return newCount;
        });
      },
      error(err: any): void {
        console.error('err', err);
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.voteCounterSub$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<dealtd-deal-vote-counter
  [voteCount]="voteCount$ | async">
</dealtd-deal-vote-counter>
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class DealService {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }

  getDealVote(params) {
    const params = {
      query: getDealVote,
      variables: variables
    };
    return this.apollo.watchQuery<any>(params);
  }

  dealVoteAdded(data) {
    const params = {
      query: dealVoteAdded,
      variables: data
    };
    return getClient().subscribe(params);
  }
}
```

**schemas**

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const VoteCountFragment = {
  entry: gql`
    fragment vote on VoteType {
      voteCount
      __typename
    }
  `
};

export const dealVoteAdded = gql`
  subscription dealVoteAdded($externalId: String!) {
    dealVoteAdded(externalId: $externalId) {
      ...vote
    }
  }
  ${VoteCountFragment.entry}
`;

export const getDealVote = gql`
  query getDealVote($externalId: String!) {
    getDealVote(externalId: $externalId) {
      ...vote
    }
  }
  ${VoteCountFragment.entry}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a BehaviorSubject observable in the service in these cases

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

let bSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  getDealVote(params) {
    const params = {
      query: getDealVote,
      variables: variables
    };
       bSubject.next(new value);
  }
```

in the parent component

```
this.voteCount$ = this.dealService.bSubject
```

Answer (score 0):

use `apollo.subsribe` instead of `getClient().subscribe`.
`apollo.subsribe` warps apollo client subsribe with an angular zone.